# Integration/request rspec test of my SOAP service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, rspec, savon

I have part of my rails 2 webservice application which is used as SOAP service (historical reasons, rest of app is REST).
Just two operations `AddLead` and `ShowLead`, with wsdl on `/soap/wsdl`.

I want to test this operations by Rspec  integrations tests.
Trying to use Savon gem (`/spec/integration/soap_spec.rb`):

```
require "spec_helper"
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

describe "Leads" do

  before(:all) do
    wsdl=   "http://localhost:3000/soap/wsdl"
    wsdl = "http://www.example.com/soap/wsdl"
    @client = Savon.client(:wsdl => wsdl )

    puts("WSDL actions: #{@client.operations}")
  end
end
```

But I can not find which URL I should use to point to WSDL.

URL `localhost:3000` does not work, ending with error:

```
 Errno::ECONNREFUSED in 'Leads before(:all)'
 Connection could not be made, because target server it actively denied. - connect(2)
```

URL `www.example.com` (which is output from test url helpers) does not work either, ending with error:

```
   Wasabi::Resolver::HTTPError in 'Leads before(:all)'
   Error: 302
```

Any ideas?

Foton

Comment: Also tried just realtive path `/soap/wsdl` (as used in REST integration Rspec tests; eg. `get "resource/id.xml"`). Result was: `Errno::ENOENT in 'Leads before(:all)'
No such file or directory - /soap/wsdl`

Comment: The `:wsdl` option expects the URL to the WSDL document of your service. I'm not sure which port Rails uses during tests (try `http://test.host:80`), but I would suggest to use Rails' URL-Helpers to set the corrent host and port for you.

Comment: Helper `soap_wsdl_url()`  points to `http://www.example.com/soap/wsdl`. This adres I already tried with Wasabi::Resolver::HTTPError (see above).

Comment: No idea. Did you try to hit the URL with some HTTP client? Just to make sure it responds correctly.

Comment: If you google the `Errno::ECONNREFUSED` error message, you may find something related to your setup. If that doesn't work out for you, please try to reproduce the problem in a new Rails app with just the code needed for this error to occur and push it to GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following link: http://blog.johnsonch.com/2013/04/18/rails-3-soap-and-testing-oh-my/

Inside of your describe block use the HTTPI rack adapter, and then configure that adapter to mount your application. This will give you the ability to use a specific url.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'savon'

describe API::MyService do
  HTTPI.adapter = :rack
  HTTPI::Adapter::Rack.mount 'application', MyApp::Application

  it 'can get a response' do
    application_base = "http://application"
    client = Savon::Client.new({:wsdl => application_base + '/soap/wsdl' })
    ...
    ...
  end
  ...
```